# no match for ‘operator==’

Tags: c++, maps

I am having trouble figuring out what error there is in my code. It is supposed to take the input map and find the certain string in the key. If it finds that string in the key of a pair, it is supposed to add values associated with the key to a vector and find the final sum. I keep getting this error, though.

```
no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘const char’ and ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>’)
```

And I am unsure where in my code this error would arise. Here is my code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <map>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;
using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::map;

int GetPointTotalForStudent(map<string, string> &input, string type_of){
    vector<int> temp;
    std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), input.begin(), [type_of, temp](auto a) mutable{
        if(std::find(a.first.begin(), a.first.end(), type_of) != a.first.end()){
            temp.push_back(std::stoi(a.second));
        }
    });
    int total = std::accumulate(temp.begin(), temp.end(), 0);
    return total;
}

int main(){
    map<string, string> TP_Map;
    string type_of = "Exam";
    TP_Map.insert({"Exam 1", "80"});
    TP_Map.insert({"Project", "75"});
    TP_Map.insert({"Exam 2", "90"});
    GetPointTotalForStudent(TP_Map, type_of);
}
```

Comment: `I am unsure where` - does not the compiler show the error message with the code location?

Comment: It does not give me an exact line of where the error is

Comment: You are iterating the characters in the `std::find` function and comparing them with a `std::string`

Comment: @JoeyLafeir post the entire error.

Comment: That is the entire error it gives me for some reason

Comment: …. C++ errors, especially when dealing with templates are usually longer than a Costco receipt.

Comment: Either way, @vikAy looks to be correct. Change your code to call the string member function find

Comment: @Taekahn I was able to get that part solved, and now I have another error telling me something similar

Comment: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’ and ‘void’)

Comment: `a.first.find(needle)`

Comment: @Taekahn this is a different error, it's telling a very similar thing except with a pair and a void, and I can't figure out where this would be

Comment: Your signature on std::transform is incorrect. std::transform takes in an input container _and_ an output container. I would just iterate the container. That may or may not be your current issue.

Comment: @Taekahn is what I'm doing not iterating over the container for the output?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to c++ 17 you can do something like the following, which preserves your original vision.

```
  return std::transform_reduce(
      input.begin(), input.end(), 0, std::plus(), [type_of](auto a) {
        if (a.first.find(type_of) != std::string::npos) {
          return std::stoi(a.second);
        }
        return 0;
      });
```

However, I think you might have overcomplicated the design by using std::transform, I personally would probably favor something simpler like:

```
  int total = 0;

  for(const auto& kvp : input){
    if(kvp.first.find(type_of) != std::string::npos){
      total += std::stoi(kvp.second);
    }
  }

  return total;
```

using std::for_each

```
  int total = 0;

  std::for_each(input.begin(), input.end(), [type_of, &total](auto kvp) {
    if (kvp.first.find(type_of) != std::string::npos) {
      total += std::stoi(kvp.second);
    }
  });

  return total;
```

Comment: Sadly I am not allowed to use any loops in my solution, and in trying the solution above, I am a bit confused what that is returning overall

Comment: The first one does what your original code was trying to do, but it does it in one line without any extra containers or variables.  
If you can't use a "self written" loop, i would suggest trying `std::for_each` instead.

Comment: I actually got it working, thank you very much for all of your help!!